# How to fix :"Cannot cast activity to fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I want set fragment but still accesing parent in mainactivity.

I have 3 layout mainActivity M, fragment A and layout popup B that shown when button on fragment A onclick.
I want to send data from layout B (fragment) to fragment A with interface. onAttach procedure, its not working when set the fragment. Still accesing parent activity. Result for this null poin.
Here error code located :

```java
interfaceOnInputListener = (OnInputListener) context;
```

I have tried replaced context with `getActivity().getApplicationContext()`. But still not working.

Here completed code in myPopUpWindow

```java
public class myPopUpWindow extends DialogFragment {

    private static final String TAG = "myPopUpWindow";

    public interface OnInputListener{
        void sendOutput(String output);
    }

    public OnInputListener interfaceOnInputListener;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_wind,container,false);

        final TextView tbxEdT = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        Button btnOK = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
        btnOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String strInput = tbxEdT.getText().toString();

                interfaceOnInputListener.sendOutput(strInput);
                getDialog().dismiss();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            interfaceOnInputListener = (OnInputListener) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onAttach: ClassCastException: " + e.getMessage() );
        }
     }
}
```

This is in mainactivity codes

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            loadFragment();

        }

        private boolean loadFragment(){
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                       .replace(R.id.frame_container,new AFragment())
                       .addToBackStack(null)
                       .commit();
           return  true;
       }
   }
```

Here xml that contain frame for fragment

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frame_container"
                android:layout_width="395dp"
                android:layout_height="715dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

            </FrameLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I want send data from myPopUpWindow to fragment A. But error on cast activity to fragment. Any sugestion ?

Comment: instead of interfaceOnInputListener = (OnInputListener) context;
do interfaceOnInputListener=this

Comment: Have you implemented `OnInputListener` in your activity?

Comment: @NatigBabayev, i've implemented it on fragment A. Because i want in it the output data that sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After workaround on it, finally the problem is solved. But I change it with intent and on Fragment A, got it onActivityResult.

here code in pop up dialog

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("class",spnSubClass.getSelectedItem().toString());
                intent.putExtra("month",strSelectedMonth);
                getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
                dismiss();
```

And got it in fragment A :

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case POPUPDIALOG:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    //--- get value from dialog
                    Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
                    strClass = bundle.getString("class");
                    strMonth = bundle.getString("month");                                             
                    } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                //
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`interfaceOnInputListener = (OnInputListener) getTargetFragment();`

here is a similar program. Refer this for more understanding.

https://github.com/mitchtabian/DialogFragmentToFragment/tree/master/DialogFragmentFragment/app/src/main/java/codingwithmitch/com/dialogfragmentfragment

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you managed it since you didn't share the activity code. You shouldn't directly convert `context` into your interface. This could cause potential crashes as well as create a bad code because your dialog fragment is reyling on its caller to implement. Try with the approach as follows.

In your dialog fragment:

```
public class YourDialogFragment : DialogFragment {
      @Nullable private OnInputListener onInputListener;

      public setInputListener(onInputListener : OnInputListener) {
            this.onInputListener = onInputListener
      }

      //Other codes here
      //Make sure to null check with this code before sending
      // if (this.onInputListener != null) { onInputListener.doSth() }

      @Override
      public void onDestroy {
            this.interfaceOnInputListener = null
            super. onDestroy()
      }

}
```

And then you can set the listener through the exposed method when you create the dialog fragment, for example say you have this function in your acitivty

```
class YourActivity : AppCompatActivity {

    public void showDialog() {
        public final dialogFragment = YourDialogFragment()
        dialogFragment.setInputListener(this) //this can be whatever interface implmenetation you want
        dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "TAG_HERE")
    }
}
```

This way, even if you refactor the logic later, you wn't have to worry about type casting fail or context being null. Another thing this approach helps is that the fragment no longer depends on its caller to implement the interface, so it's good for testing later as well.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. See my edit (add code on mainactivity). The dialog appears from fragment A when button clicked.

Comment: @xdcomx Then you just implement the listener in fragment A and pass it to the method in the dialog

Comment: thanks alot. But forgive me several day ago, i have solve it with sent using intent and on  fragment A, got it onActivityResult.